# How do I find the most efficient route through a train network if i want to go to all stations?

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-optimization

I want to go to all the stations on the Singapore MRT.
This is image of mrt map as of 2024:

[image: image of mrt map as of 2024]

Assume this MRT network is an undirected, weighted, sparse graph where stations are vertices and tracks are edges, and the edges are weighted by the time taken between each station.

What is the fastest route if the start and end points do not have to be the same?

I don't see how I could use TSP or OTSP since they both state you can only visit a city once when there are a few "deadends" in the MRT map which necessitates going back to the same station.

sidenote: I am just a high school student and still new to graph theory

Comment: You're essentially rediscovering the [traveling salesperson problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), although not quite since the start and end points can be different.

Comment: but the TSP states that you can only travel to one city once and just by looking at the map I don't see how I can not do that since there are multiple branches in the network with one way in and one way out -- like a dead end

Comment: This is not a good example for you to learn much of anything. See what you can do for far fewer vertices, just make some drawings yourself

Comment: Look into simulated annealing.  These sorts of problems are hard and generally we settle for approximate solutions.

Comment: See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39833023/tsp-where-vertices-can-be-visited-multiple-times)